# How can i do fix the chromakey in my code

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, frame, mindar

I am trying to add chroma key in my code code from github its  not working its show me blank screen when i add chramakey. Chromakey code get from github
i want to add chromakey in my code please help me. I am trying since long time please help me
i am new bie
my code are given below

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hiukim/mind-ar-js@1.1.5/dist/mindar-image.prod.js"></script>
      <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hiukim/mind-ar-js@1.1.5/dist/mindar-image-aframe.prod.js"></script>
  
      <script>
        const showInfo = () => {
          let y = 0;
          
          const webButton = document.querySelector("#web-button");
          
          const youtubeButton = document.querySelector("#youtube-button");
          const text = document.querySelector("#text");
  
          
          setTimeout(() => {
            webButton.setAttribute("visible", true);
          }, 100);
        
          setTimeout(() => {
            youtubeButton.setAttribute("visible", true);
          }, 100);
  
          let currentTab = '';
          webButton.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
            text.setAttribute("value", "https://homevism.com");
            currentTab = 'web';
          });
         
        
         youtubeButton.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
            console.log("loc");
            text.setAttribute("value", "https://www.youtube.com");
            currentTab = 'youtube';
          });
  
          text.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
            if (currentTab === 'web') {
              window.location.href="https://homevism.com";
            }
          });
        }
  
        const showPortfolio = (done) => {
          const portfolio = document.querySelector("#portfolio-panel");
          const portfolioLeftButton = document.querySelector("#portfolio-left-button");
          const portfolioRightButton = document.querySelector("#portfolio-right-button");
          const paintandquestPreviewButton = document.querySelector("#paintandquest-preview-button");
  
          let y = 0;
          let currentItem = 0;
  
          portfolio.setAttribute("visible", true);
  
          const showPortfolioItem = (item) => {
            for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
              document.querySelector("#portfolio-item" + i).setAttribute("visible", i === item);
            }
          }
          const id = setInterval(() => {
            y += 0.008;
            if (y >= 0.6) {
              clearInterval(id);
              portfolioLeftButton.setAttribute("visible", false);
              portfolioRightButton.setAttribute("visible", false);
              portfolioLeftButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                currentItem = (currentItem + 1) % 3;
                showPortfolioItem(currentItem);
              });
              portfolioRightButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                currentItem = (currentItem - 1 + 3) % 3;
                showPortfolioItem(currentItem);
              });
              const testVideo = document.createElement( "video" );
            const canplayWebm = testVideo.canPlayType( 'video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' );
            document.querySelector("#paintandquest-video-link").setAttribute("src", "#paintandquest-video-mp4");
                document.querySelector("#paintandquest-video-mp4").play();
              // paintandquestPreviewButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
              //   paintandquestPreviewButton.setAttribute("visible", false);
              //   const testVideo = document.createElement( "video" );
              //   const canplayWebm = testVideo.canPlayType( 'video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' );
              //   if (canplayWebm == "") {
              //     document.querySelector("#paintandquest-video-link").setAttribute("src", "#paintandquest-video-mp4");
              //     document.querySelector("#paintandquest-video-mp4").play();
              //   } else {
              //     document.querySelector("#paintandquest-video-link").setAttribute("src", "#paintandquest-video-webm");
              //     document.querySelector("#paintandquest-video-webm").play();
              //   }
              // });
  
              setTimeout(() => {
                done();
              }, 100);
            }
            portfolio.setAttribute("position", "0 " + y + " -0.01");
          }, 10);
        }
  
        const showAvatar = (onDone) => {
          const avatar = document.querySelector("#avatar");
          let z = -0.3;
          const id = setInterval(() => {
            z += 0.008;
            if (z >= 0.2) {
              clearInterval(id);
              onDone();
            }
            avatar.setAttribute("position", "0 -0.25 " + z);
          }, 10);
        }
  
        AFRAME.registerComponent('mytarget', {
          init: function () {
            this.el.addEventListener('targetFound', event => {
              console.log("target found");
              showAvatar(() => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  showPortfolio(() => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      showInfo();
                    }, 100);
                  });
                }, 100);
              });
            });
            this.el.addEventListener('targetLost', event => {
              console.log("target found");
            });
            //this.el.emit('targetFound');
          }
        });
      </script>
  
      <style>
        body {
          margin: 0;
        }
        .example-container {
          overflow: hidden;
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
       
        #example-scanning-overlay {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background: transparent;
      z-index: 2;
        }
        @media (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
      #example-scanning-overlay .inner {
        width: 50vh;
        height: 50vh;
      }
        }
        @media (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
      #example-scanning-overlay .inner {
        width: 80vw;
        height: 80vw;
      }
        }
  
        #example-scanning-overlay .inner {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      position: relative;
  
      background:
        linear-gradient(to right, white 10px, transparent 10px) 0 0,
        linear-gradient(to right, white 10px, transparent 10px) 0 100%,
        linear-gradient(to left, white 10px, transparent 10px) 100% 0,
        linear-gradient(to left, white 10px, transparent 10px) 100% 100%,
        linear-gradient(to bottom, white 10px, transparent 10px) 0 0,
        linear-gradient(to bottom, white 10px, transparent 10px) 100% 0,
        linear-gradient(to top, white 10px, transparent 10px) 0 100%,
        linear-gradient(to top, white 10px, transparent 10px) 100% 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 40px 40px;
        }
  
        #example-scanning-overlay.hidden {
      display: none;
        }
  
        #example-scanning-overlay img {
      opacity: 0.6;
      width: 90%;
      align-self: center;
        }
  
        #example-scanning-overlay .inner .scanline {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 10px;
      background: white;
      animation: move 2s linear infinite;
        }
        @keyframes move {
      0%, 100% { top: 0% }
      50% { top: calc(100% - 10px) }
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="example-container">
        <div id="example-scanning-overlay" class="hidden">
      <div class="inner">
        <img src="Visiting Card Back 2.jpg"/>
        <div class="scanline"></div>
      </div>
        </div>
  <script>
   var imageData = paintandquest-video-link.getImageData(0, 0, paintandquest-video-link.width, paintandquest-video-link.height);
var data = imageData.data;
var start = {
red: data[0],
green: data[1],
blue: data[2]
};
// iterate over all pixels
var tolerance = 150;
for(var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; i += 4) {
var diff = Math.abs(data[i] - data[0]) + Math.abs(data[i+1] - data[1]) + Math.abs(data[i+2] - data[2]);
if(diff < tolerance) {
data[i + 3] = 0;
}
}
paintandquest-video-link.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  </script>
        <a-scene mindar-image="imageTargetSrc: targets1.mind; showStats: false; uiScanning: #example-scanning-overlay;" embedded color-space="sRGB" renderer="colorManagement: true, physicallyCorrectLights" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" device-orientation-permission-ui="enabled: false">
          <a-assets>
            <img id="card" src="Visiting Card Back 2.jpg" />
            <img id="icon-web" src="webicon.png" />
            <img id="icon-youtube" src="youtubeicon.png" />
           
            <!-- <img id="icon-play" src="playicon.png" /> -->
            <img id="icon-left" src="./assets/card-example/icons/left.png" />
            <img id="icon-right" src="./assets/card-example/icons/right.png" />
            <!-- <img id="paintandquest-preview" src="./assets/card-example/portfolio/paintandquest-preview.png" /> -->
            <video id="paintandquest-video-mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true" src="green.mp4"></video>
            <video id="paintandquest-video-webm" autoplay="true" loop="true" src="green.mp4"></video>
            <img id="coffeemachine-preview" src="./assets/card-example/portfolio/coffeemachine-preview.png" />
            <img id="peak-preview" src="./assets/card-example/portfolio/peak-preview.png" />
            
            <a-asset-item id="avatarModel" src=""></a-asset-item>
          </a-assets>
  
          <a-camera position="0 0 0" look-controls="enabled: false" cursor="fuse: false; rayOrigin: mouse;" raycaster="far: 10000; objects: .clickable">
          </a-camera>
  
          <a-entity id="mytarget" mytarget mindar-image-target="targetIndex: 0">
            <a-plane src="#card" position="0 0 0" height="0.552" width="1" rotation="0 0 0"></a-plane>
  
            <a-entity visible=false id="portfolio-panel" position="0 0 -0.01">
              <a-text value="Portfolio" color="black" align="center" width="2" position="0 0.4 0"></a-text>
              <a-entity id="portfolio-item0">
                <a-video id="paintandquest-video-link" webkit-playsinline playsinline width="1" height="0.552" position="0 0 0"></a-video>
                <!-- <a-image id="paintandquest-preview-button" class="clickable" src="#paintandquest-preview" alpha-test="0.5" position="0 0 0" height="0.552" width="1"> -->
                </a-image>
              </a-entity>
              <a-entity id="portfolio-item1" visible=false>
                <a-image class="clickable" src="#coffeemachine-preview" alpha-test="0.5" position="0 0 0" height="0.552" width="1">
                </a-image>
              </a-entity>
              <a-entity id="portfolio-item2" visible=false>
                <a-image class="clickable" src="#peak-preview" alpha-test="0.5" position="0 0 0" height="0.552" width="1">
                </a-image>
              </a-entity>
  
              <a-image visible=false id="portfolio-left-button" class="clickable" src="#icon-left" position="-0.7 0 0" height="0.15" width="0.15"></a-image>
              <a-image visible=false id="portfolio-right-button" class="clickable" src="#icon-right" position="0.7 0 0" height="0.15" width="0.15"></a-image>
            </a-entity>
  
         <a-image visible=false id="youtube-button" class="clickable" onclick="window.open('https://youtube.com', '_blank')" src="#icon-youtube" position="-0.42 -0.5 0" height="0.15" width="0.15"
              animation="property: scale; to: 1.2 1.2 1.2; dur: 1000; easing: easeInOutQuad; loop: true; dir: alternate"
            ></a-image>
  
            <a-image visible=false id="web-button" onclick="window.open('https://homevism.com', '_blank')" class="clickable" src="#icon-web" alpha-test="0.5" position="-0.14 -0.5 0" height="0.15" width="0.15"
              animation="property: scale; to: 1.2 1.2 1.2; dur: 1000; easing: easeInOutQuad; loop: true; dir: alternate"
            ></a-image>
  
  
           
  
            <a-gltf-model id="avatar" rotation="0 0 0" position="0 -0.25 0" scale="0.004 0.004 0.004" src="#avatarModel"></a-gltf-model>
  
            <a-text id="text" class="clickable" value="" color="black" align="center" width="2" position="0 -1 0" geometry="primitive:plane; height: 0.1; width: 2;" material="opacity: 0.5"></a-text>
          </a-entity>
        </a-scene>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Github chromakey i am applying the link given below please anybody help me to fix the problem i am very thankful to you
https://github.com/nikolaiwarner/aframe-chromakey-material/tree/master/example
Here is my output of my code
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17jAtPLFYQ2mTf8iSiOfD52IHmTVooWKW?usp=sharing

Comment: do you get any errors in the browser console (hint: you do)

Comment: look  `paintandquest-video-link` - does that look right?

Comment: there is no error when target image found please can you try i am thankful to you

Comment: i try everything i cannot understand this id give me confuse. and i am fail

Comment: so, `paintandquest-video-link` looks correct to you? `paintandquest` minus `video` minus `link`

Comment: you can't have `-` in a variable name ... and I can't believe you have no errors in the browser console - do you know what the browser console is?

Comment: i check and i remove the minus..it also show me same problem...i am using window google chrome console

Comment: well, no idea what that variable was supposed to be - it's YOUR code after all